# Grounding Case to AC ground causing IO errors on PCB

Tags: grounding

I have a PCB that is powered by a AC/DC power supply. The PCB also has a aluminum heatsink attached to it. This setup functions normally when outside it’s case, as soon as the PCB and psu is mounted in the case there is lot of IO errors on some of the IO lines on the PCB. This happens when the case is grounded on AC mains ground (the heatsink is also attached to the case which is grounded together with the psu to AC ground). Why is grounding the case causing this and how can it be fixed (the case is made of aluminum)?

I’m guessing noise from AC ground is being injected into the case and into the heatsink that is against the IO lines on the PCB causing the errors?

Comment: With the info given the problem could be anywhere. There's no data sheet of the power supply,  no schematics, no wiring diagram.

Comment: Well the problem only occurs in a specific case, when the PCB is mounted to the case via its heatsink, so the heatsink is essentially grounded to the PSU earth ground. Removing either the earth ground coming in from the AC socket, or isolating the heatsink from the case solves the issue

Answer (score 2):

So I isolated the issue to the heatsink that is attached closely to the PCB being in contact with earth ground from the case screws. If the heatsink is isolated the issue goes away.

The heatsink is also not electrically grounded to PCB ground, so I want to test if I ground the heatsink to PCB ground and keep the heatsink connected to earth ground if that will also solve the issue since its a simpler solution than isolating the heatsink from the case

Comment: Whatever is attached to the heatsink have a metal tab that is effectively grounded when you put the pcb into the case. Datasheet for that device will tell you what connects to the tab, and you can draw your own conclusion if it's a good idea to have it grounded or not. (Since you experiences a less desired behavior it's probably not a good idea.)

Comment: Also grounded PCB ground to heatsink, this also made the issue go away. But now AC mains ground is connected to case, which is connected to heatsink and also connected to PCB ground which is probably not a good idea

Comment: It depends. If you conclude that you application should do without that connection, there are ways to isolate heatsink from the components tab or the heatsink from the chassis, but you already know this.

Comment: This is hard to follow and understand.  Our board level heat sinks (for conductive cooling of the board) are always in direct contact with the chassis (needed for conductive cooling), which in turn is always grounded (for safety reasons).  This is our standard implementation, and we never have to isolate the board level heat sinks.  There is something else going on here.